# If $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ then $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(y,x)}{\partial y}$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Why is it that if $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ then $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(y,x)}{\partial y}$ for all $x,y$ in $\Bbb R^2$. My lecturer just went over it like it was obvious but I cant seem to come up with a proof with why it is so. I thought maybe starting from the limit definition of a partial derivative would get me somewhere then I could jumble it till they were equal but this got me nowhere.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps when we derivate $f(x,y)$ about first coordinate, it's the same which we derivate about first coordinate of $f(y,x)$

Answer (score 2):

The formula is correct as long as you interpret it as
$$
\partial_1 f(x,y) = \partial_2 f(y,x).
$$
Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y) & =f(y,x) \\
f(x+h,y) &= f(y,x+h).
\end{align}
$$
Now subtract and divide by $h$.

Comment: Yes, that interpretation question is key here.  This formula is a bit of sleight of hand.

Answer (score 0):

Not true at all.  For example, try $f(x,y) = xy$.

Comment: As I read it, the LHS is taken at the point $(x,y)$, the RHS at the point $(y,x)$.

Comment: I do not think you are right... Here $(x,y)$ is the point where we compute the derivative, not the variables...